# Does adding a print statement in a loop add a significant overhead for large numbers?

Tags: python

I have a very large list of around 40 items. I am finding and printing its power set. So, the complexity of my code is **n*2<sup>n</sup>**. Undoubtedly, it is taking a long time. But, if I remove the print statement, will it bring any significant improvement to the runtime of code. In other words, is print adding a significant overhead?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: Yes, feel free to time it yourself. In general the answer is yes. I/O is a significant burden in terms of performance, in general.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need the powerset? Or is that more of an exercise instead of "doing something"?

Comment: @syntonym I am doing a project in which I am trying to run all the possible queries on basis of different columns of different tables. So, I need the powerset.

Comment: @user2740957, are you using itertools?

Comment: No. I wrote my own function for it in the line of http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/

Comment: Might find itertools.combinations useful

Comment: Whatever you're doing that requires you to execute all possible query variations, find a different way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Printing isn't very CPU consuming itself, but a lot of OSes has got an artificial limit on the speed of printing characters to the command line, so I think it will be very significant (maybe even a hundred times slower).

Answer (score 0):

Printing that many elements will take a non-trivial amount of time, even if it's in fact a small fraction of the total. If your numbers are extremely large (e.g., hundreds of digits), the overhead of converting them to decimal is also going to be a factor.  Certainly, if you want to optimize a loop it won't hurt to take out the output (you can still print a short message every million iterations, or whatever). But all this can only shave a percentage of your runtime. To really speed up your code, look for an approach that does not require you to churn through all elements in the power set.